# I want to hide the SharePoint Ribbon Tabs (Browse, Page, etc) on my homepage based on permissions and such that they are stripped/trimmed when hidden

Tags: ribbon, branding, design

I am trying to hide the SharePoint Ribbon Tabs based on a users permissions. I know that I can use the SPSecurityTrimmedControl to do this but I need to wrap it around just the tabs and not the whole ribbon. The reason for this is because I am trying to 'lighten' the page for the user as I believe that there are some javascript associated with using the tabs and we don't want that to be downloaded with the page if a user doesn't use the tabs.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: There is no JS file associated just with the tabs. If you want to remove some JS files from downloading, then you'll have to change the master page.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is to follow these steps :)

- Open the master page, find the div tag:

  Put the following around it:

> ```
> <Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="ManageWeb">
> <div id="s4-ribbonrow" …</div>
> </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
> ```

or you can follow this [Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2012/04/30/how-to-hide-the-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010-rajeswari-mohandas.aspx), it shows you three ways of doing it but I guess you dont want to use javascript as once I used it and it broke few things

If you want to dig it deep check these links out

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010customization/thread/9e52de43-7941-4e61-976b-d6bf2f8d926c

http://fusionovation.com/blogs/mbell/archive/2008/09/18/security-trimmed-controls-in-sharepoint.aspx

http://sharepoint.smayes.com/2011/02/hiding-the-sharepoint-2010-ribbon-for-readers-a-proof-of-concept/

Hope this helped you solving your issue :)

Comment: I want to keep the ribbonrow - I just need to hide the tabs in that row. The user still needs to be able to see the welcome control and there are also some links (Home, Contact, etc) that are placed there that need to be viewed at all times.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :)

http://johanolivier.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/show-or-hide-sharepoint-ribbon-tab.html

hope it helps you!

Comment: Link only answer! Try and get some time to update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using CSOM:

Visit this link it will definitely help you
[Hiding browse and page tab from SharePoint 2013 for specific users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184047/hiding-browse-and-page-tab-from-sharepoint-2013-for-specific-users/184053#184053)